# Responsive problem on Iphone devices when width of element set to 50%

Tags: html, css

I'm creating simple list that has 4 items in line on fullscreen. Under 767px width they should have 50% width but on Iphone there is a problem.

I created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L20mj5sn/1/) with html and css.

```css
.list-benefits-index {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-content: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-benefits-index li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list-benefits-index li > span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-benefits-index li > span a {
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list-benefits-index li > span a > span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-benefits-index li > span a i {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #4ea2ec;
}

.list-benefits-index li > span a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .list-benefits-index li {
            width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .list-benefits-index li > span a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .list-benefits-index li > span a i {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-benefits-index">
    <li>
        <span>
           <a href="/vyhody-nakupu">
               <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                <span>Vše skladem</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
           <a href="/vyhody-nakupu">
               <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                <span>Doprava zdarma nad 300 Kč</span>

            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
           <a href="/vyhody-nakupu">
               <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                <span>Doručení do 1 dne<br>při objednání do 14:00</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
           <a href="/vyhody-nakupu">
               <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                <span>Každý týden<br>nové zboží</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://ctrlv.cz/F7w4 screen with Iphone layout.

I don't own Apple device so i can't find out what the problem is, if i set the responsive width to 100% it displays right but if i set it to 50% it breaks.

Comment: Have a [read of this](https://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) as your selectors are very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

use with all browser support property like -o-, -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-

Answer (score 0):

This is a common cross browser compatibility. Each browser has its own way to interpret the content of a web page, so there might be some differences at your web page from one browser to another.

[This](http://browserhacks.com/) might be helpful for your problem.

If you don't own an iOS device you can download Safari web browser or use a cross browser compatibility test tool([here are a few tools)](https://www.guru99.com/top-10-cross-browser-testing-tools.html)

I also recommend you to read [this article about cross browser compatibility](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-make-a-cross-browser-compatible-website/)

Finally, your CSS can be improved. Take a look [here](https://magora-systems.com/how-to-use-css-selectors/).